# Sitecore and TDS and Package Deployment

Tags: msbuild, sitecore, teamcity, tds

I'm using TDS to create .update packages. I've set the settings for this in TDS properties. This works fine locally. But on my build server (TeamCity) it does not seem to build the update packages. Do I need to add some command line parameters for this? I've tried using the MSBuild runner, and using a script file that calls MSBuild.exe. I've also tried putting my TDS settings in a TdsGlobal.config. It just not create the .update files, or even the directory where they should go.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?  Any messages in the build log indicating that the TDS project is being built at all?  If you use a different build configuration on the build server, the TDS project might not be set to build with the solution.

Comment: Figured it out. The "Update Package" settings need to be set as parameters of msbuild. I was not getting any error messages. Which was frustrating. To say the least.

Comment: You should answer the question yourself and mark it as the answer for anyone else who has this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is you need to set the TDS Update Package settings as part of your command line parameters, so:

```
msbuild.exe /p:GeneratePackage=${generatePackage};PackageAuthor=${packageAuthor};PackagePublisher=${packagePublisher};etc...
```

These settings are also set in the visual studio solution -> TDS project -> Properties. I dont have time to experiment if I can remove them from visual studio, but I expect that I can.